# Adding data from master spreadsheet to other spreadsheets based on specific criteria?

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

I have thirteen spreadsheets in my workbook, the first spreadsheet is my master schedule that contains a table with the column headers: "Location", "Equipment", "Make/Model", "Serial #" and "Calibration Due Date". My twelve other spreadsheets have tables with these same column headers, with each one corresponding to the different months.

When I enter data into a row in the master schedule, I want that data to be automatically entered into one of the twelve other spreadsheets based on the "Calibration Due Date". For example, if I enter a row of data in my master schedule that contains a Calibration Due Date of 01/16/15, I want that row of data to ONLY be inserted into the table in the January spreadsheet.

I wrote a formula in each of the monthly spreadsheets that causes the data entered into the master schedule to be automatically entered into that spreadsheet, I then set the filter for the 'Calibration Due Date" column to only January for the January spreadsheet and I did the same for the rest of the months, however, when new data is added to the master schedule, that row of data is entered into every spreadsheet instead of a single spreadsheet corresponding to the date, the filters on the spreadsheets don't work on new data that gets added.

How can a row of data entered into the master schedule be automatically entered into only one other spreadsheet based on the "Calibration Due Date" month?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you seem to be aiming for may require something like VBA, though your question is not tagged that way (and if it were and you don't post code you risk downvotes and close votes). However an alternative would be to create the subsidiary sheets on demand by drilling down from a PivotTable. This though would effectively require that any data added directly into the subsidiary sheets be considered disposable.